# PySerial Python error: AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute '_port_handle'

Tags: android, python, tornado, pyserial

I try to talk serial with Python with HTML and JavaScript.
Background is that i need a interface on Android to control serial devices connected to the USB port of a Tablet or Phone. I did web design and building the interface would be easy for me with HTML, CSS, JS.
Maybe there is a better way (?) but the only example i found is this:
http://fabacademy.org/archives/2015/doc/WebSocketConsole.html

So i did install:

```
Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package Eng (x86)
Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package Eng (x64)
Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 v9.0.0.30729 Eng
Python x86 v2.7.11
```

And in CMD:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
python -m pip install --upgrade virtualenv
python -m pip install --upgrade wheel
python -m pip install --upgrade pyserial
python -m pip install --upgrade tornado
python -m pip install --upgrade multiprocessing
```

The problem with the example from that side i get:

```
AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute '_port_handle'
```

Since i never did much with Python - I'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it appears that the example code will not work as the multiprocessing library starts a new process and that can't access the serial object created by the main process.

To fix it:

In the `serialworker.py` file, move the line `self.sp = serial.Serial(SERIAL_PORT, SERIAL_BAUDRATE)` from the `__init__` function to the first line of the `run` function.